# Constructing Datetime from 3 integers in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new on MVC3 and not familiar with the unit testing part. I have been trying to construct Datetime with exception handling from accepting 3 integer value but the it fails the unit testing. Im not sure i am doing it correctly or not.

This is the controller part:

```
public DateTime MakeDate(string dateString)
    {
     DateTime myDate;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate))
        {
            return myDate;
        }
        return new DateTime();
    }
```

And this is the unit Testing:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MakeDateConstructsADateTimeFromYearMonthAndDay()
{
    //Arrange
    var controller = new DateController();
    var expected = new DateTime(2014, 6, 30);

    //Act
    var result = controller.MakeDate(2014, 6, 30);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual<DateTime>(expected, result);
}

[TestMethod]
public void MakeDateReturnsDefaultDateTimeIfInputDataInvalid()
{
    var controller = new DateController();
    var expected = new DateTime();

    //Act
    //June has only 30 days so this will cause an exception
    var result = controller.MakeDate(2014, 6, 31);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual<DateTime>(expected, result);
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: **How** does it fail? What error do you get?

Comment: Error: No overload for Method "Makedate" takes 3 arguments

Comment: You are mistaking your `MakeDate` function for the `DateTime` constructor. Your function takes only one parameter, which is a `DateTime`. So it could be called like this: `controller.MakeDate(new DateTime(2014, 6, 30));`
If you want to pass a `string`, change the `dr` type to `string` and call it like this: `controller.MakeDate("2014-06-30");`

Comment: @TarekIsmail: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: how do i input 3 arguments ? i have modified my code above

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = "2014-06-30";
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Your `date` string is not of the format you use in `ParseExact`.

You are using `yyyyMMdd` when you should be using `yyyy-MM-dd`.

The code fails because the string doesn't match the format.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `MakeDate` function to something like this:

```
DateTime myDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate))
{
    return myDate;
}
return new DateTime();
```

Also, your `MakeDate` function doesn't use the `dr` parameter and you specify a date in format `yyyy-MM-dd` and use `ParseExact` with a different format (`yyyyMMdd`).

Comment: are you passing "dateString" as string parameter in "MakeDate" method ?

Comment: Yes. Change your `dr` parameter to string. The function would be:`public DateTime MakeDate(string dateString) { ... }`

Comment: Even though i change it still it shows error in the test class. Error is "No overload for method MakeDate takes 3 arguments"